# AppleScript choose file dialog box store last folder opened in text file.

Tags: applescript

This seems like such an easy thing to do that I'm amazed the solution is still eluding me.

I'm trying to store that last folder opened by a "choose file" dialog box. I want to store that folder's location in a text file.

I want to have my "choose file" dialog always open to the last folder used.

I've got a lot of the script working but there is one weird thing that keeps eluding me.

Look at my script...

```
set Shows to paragraphs of (read POSIX file "/Users/lowken/Documents/config.txt")

set strPathFromConfig to item 1 of Shows as string

set strPathFromConfig to ((characters 3 thru -1 of strPathFromConfig) as string)

display dialog strPathFromConfig

set strPath to (path to home folder as text) & strPathFromConfig

display dialog strPath

choose file with prompt "Please choose a file:" of type {"XLSX", "APPL"} default location alias strPath
```

The script reads my config text file which contains one line and only one string of "Documents".

I trim some leading garbage characters and display a dialog with the result of "Documents".

Then I set the strPath using the the value from the config file.

I display the new value is it is a valid location on my system.

Next I attempt to the dialog and I get an error message of "File alias Macintosh HD:Users:lowken:Documents of  wasn't found.

Let change the script so that instead of using the value that was extracted from the config.txt file, I simply set a string variable in my script.

```
set Shows to paragraphs of (read POSIX file "/Users/lowken/Documents/config.txt")

set strPathFromConfig to item 1 of Shows as string

set strPathFromConfig to ((characters 3 thru -1 of strPathFromConfig) as string)

display dialog strPathFromConfig

set strTemp to "Documents"

set strPath to (path to home folder as text) & strTemp

display dialog strPath

choose file with prompt "Please choose a file:" of type {"XLSX", "APPL"} default location alias strPath
```

Now it works. AppleScript seems to not want to use the value that was looked up from the config.txt file.

What am I doing wrong? I tried casting to an Alias I tried different locations on my system.

It seems to me that somehow the value looked up from the text file is not a string data type.

Any ideas?

P.S.

I'm running OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 on a mid 2012 MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the encoding of your "config.txt" document.

The `read` command can read (**MacRoman**, **UTF-8** or **UTF-16**) encoded text files, but you must specify the type `class`, otherwise it read the text file as MacRoman.

```
set strPathFromConfig to paragraph 1 of (read "/Users/lowken/Documents/config.txt" as «class ut16») -- or if UTF-8 use —> as «class utf8»
set strPath to ((path to home folder as text) & strPathFromConfig) as alias
choose file with prompt "Please choose a file:" of type {"XLSX", "APPL"} default location strPath
```

For another encoding, you must change the encoding of the "**config.txt**" document.

Comment: I think that might be it. At least it makes sense to me.

Comment: that did it. How in the name of all that is good in the world do you type the « & » symbols? I was able to copy and paste to get it to work but I would love to know how to type those symbols.

Comment: This depends on the keyboard. On **U.S.** keyboard :
Press **Shift + \ keys** to type left double angle bracket.
Press **Option + Shift + \  keys** to type right double angle bracket.

Answer (score 1):

The default location of the choose file command can be a Unix path "/Users/my_user/Documents" or a Finder path with Alias before like : alias "HD:Users:my_User:Documents"
so first check that strPath is the correct value, then if OK, double check the class of it :

```
Display Dialog (class of strPath) as string
```

it may not be OK and you have to coerce the (path to home folder as string) and not text.

Comment: My gut tells me that there is something about the datatype when I extract the value from a text file that "choose file" doesn't like. I'll try casting to a string (although I think I already tried that).

Comment: in your first script, you assign path "as text"...assigned it as "string"